# Exact types for ReactWrapper in enzyme using typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, types, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing my custom components using jest with enzyme (using typescript), so I'm creating tests like:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

However, `mount`s return type is `ReactWrapper`, so I'm using it:

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

And it's still ok. But digging deeper brought me to knowledge that `ReactWrapper` is generic. And... `mount` function has 3 declarations. All the time I used it like this:

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper<MyCustomComponent> = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

But now I'm afraid it's not ok. I strongly want to use exact types. What exactly should I put into diamonds operator for `ReactWrapper`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in documentation.

`ReactWrapper` and `ShallowWrapper` has 3 generic arguments. Let's say we have:

```
export Interface ComponentProps {
    someComponentProp: string;
}

export interface ComponentState {
    someComponentState: string;
}

export class MyCustomComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {

}
```

In such a code, test DOM objects should have following types:

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper<MyCustomComponent, ComponentProps, ComponentState> = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

However, there's a problem with `find`. In following code:

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper<MyCustomComponent, ComponentProps, ComponentState> = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
const subWrapper: ReactWrapper = wrapper.find(SubComponent);
expect(subWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

the `subWrapper` type cannot be: `ReactWrapper<SubComponent, SubComponentProps, SubComponentState>` - it won't compile. It'll force using:

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper<MyCustomComponent, ComponentProps, ComponentState> = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
const subWrapper: ReactWrapper<React.Component<SubComponentProps, SubComponentState>, SubComponentProps, SubComponentState> = wrapper.find(SubComponent);
expect(subWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

It looks awful. Fortunatelly we can get our custom type using cast via `as`.

```
const wrapper: ReactWrapper<MyCustomComponent, ComponentProps, ComponentState> = mount(<MyCustomComponent/>);
const subWrapper: ReactWrapper<SubComponent, SubComponentProps, SubComponentState> = wrapper.find(SubComponent) as SubComponent;
expect(subWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you give an example for FunctionComponent please? I cannot get my head around it. For example `const Foo: FC<FooProps> = ({ bar }) => (<>{bar}</>);`

Comment: @igor you can use either `const wrapper: ShallowWrapper<typeof SomeComponent> = shallow(<SomeComponent/>);` or more implicit `const wrapper: ShallowWrapper<(props: SomeComponentProps) => JSX.Element> = shallow(<SomeComponent/>);`

Comment: ShallowWrapper's first type param is the type of the component's props, not the component itself

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using `FunctionComponent`s, the first type parameter of `ShallowWrapper`/`ReactWrapper` is the props type, so it's very simple to use:

```
type FooProps = {...};
const Foo: FunctionComponent<FooProps> = ({...}) => {
    ...
};

...

const wrapper: ShallowWrapper<FooProps> = shallow(<Foo/>);
```